# Do we need a special note on linking to research?

Tags: discussion

Came across a [messy link-only answer today](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11136/1671), and had to edit to include the titles for the papers with embedded links.

Web addresses reduce readability, and links can expire, limiting future utility.  (Ideally, we would also cite the authors, but my experience is title-only works fine for search.)

- Should we do a section in the "[What can I ask about here?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" and/or else where to specify how links to research should be handled?

Comment: Nah...A person not bothered to title the links sure won't be bothered to read any kind of instruction.

Comment: @DuttaA Sadly I have to agree.